# An interesting linear algebra question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $u$ be $n\times n$ matrix and $n\times 1$ vector of $\mathbb{C}$.

Denote $\overline{A}$ is the matrix $(\overline{A})_{ij}=A_{ij}^*$, the conjugate number; ($\overline{A}$ is not the conjugate transpose matrix) and similarly $\overline{u}$.

Prove that if $\lambda$ is a nonnegative eigenvalue of $A\overline{A}$, ie $\exists v\ne 0:A\overline{A}v=\lambda v$, then $\exists u\ne 0$ such that:
$$A\overline{u}=\sqrt{\lambda}u$$

Comment: Conjugate matrix is $(A^\dagger)_{ji}=A^*_{ij}$, which is different. I just want to avoid potential misread.

Comment: But $A^*$ is the most common notation for the [conjugate transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) (see the link) so you are only adding confusion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of Youla decomposition. See p.700, Theorem 1 of D.C. Youla, [*A normal form for a matrix under the unitary congruence group*](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1961-059-8), Canad. J. Math. 13(1961), 694-704.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I have found a simple way to directly point out the vector $u$:

- $u=\sqrt{\lambda}A\overline{v}+\lambda v$ if $\sqrt{\lambda}A\overline{v}+\lambda v\ne0$
- If $\sqrt{\lambda}A\overline{v}+\lambda v=0$ then $A\overline{v}=-\sqrt{\lambda}v$ then we choose $u=iv$

Also thanks for the elegant answer from User1551.

Thanks to Leeuwen's comment I think the more appropriate choice is $u=A\overline{v}+\sqrt{\lambda}v$

Comment: Huh? Isn't your answer the truly elegant one? ;-D

Comment: When I said elegant I mean natural and general. My way is rather a trick than a mathematical fact :)

Comment: Your second clause does not work for $\lambda=0$, which the question allows. For instance if $A$ is real nonzero but $A^2=0$, and $v$ is a non-eigenvector for $A$, then it (in fact its first "then") fails. You can avoid this trap by taking $u=A\bar v+\sqrt\lambda v$ instead, which seems a bit more natural anyway.